# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient ->

Tags: angular

This is the error i am getting while testing after upgrading to `angular 12`.

> NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient -> HttpHandler]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpHandler!

i tried adding **HttpClientModule** to imports array of **TestBed.configureTestingModule**

even my project has server-side rendering .

Please help me with this,  i have tried all solutions available but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `HttpClientTestingModule` into imports in your test file.

So your spec file could look smiliar to this

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { FftService } from './fft.service';

describe('FftService', () => {
  let service: FftService;

  beforeEach(() => { 
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(FftService);
  });

  test('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

In case you want to as well test API don't forget to import `HttpTestingController`

Spec file with controller could look like this

```
import { TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { InfoService } from './info.service';
import { InfoBackend } from '@sharedModels';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
describe('InfoService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: InfoService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [InfoService],
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.inject(InfoService);
    httpMock = injector.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });
test('Endpoint test',()=> {// do testing here})
});
```

Comment: @ankitsingh can you create stackblitz or simliar with the code or provide the code? this way I can't help more